# Почему криво работает Slick Slider?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, slider

Всем добрейшего дня! Подскажите, гуру, есть слайдер на Slick Slider'е. Есть некоторые огрехи в работе данного слайдера с превью фотографий. У меня сайт состоит из 5 секций, они же 5 страниц меню. То есть каждая секция скрыта , пока не выбран пункт меню. Когда выбираешь фотографии, открывается секция со слайдером. Главный слайд, который должен стоять по середине , смещен в право, инспектор показывает, что у slick-track прописаны два свойства, opacity: 1; width: 0px; Когда делаешь первый слай то все встает на свои места, не могу понять в чем причина, может кто сталкивался, буду признателен за подсказку!

```
<div class="foto_slider">
    <div><img src="assets/img/1.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/2.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/3.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/4.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/5.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/6.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/7.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
<div class="foto_slider-nav">
    <div><img src="assets/img/1.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/2.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/3.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/4.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/5.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/6.png" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="assets/img/7.png" alt=""></div>
</div>

$('.foto_slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  fade: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  infinite: false,
  asNavFor: '.foto_slider-nav'
)};

$('.foto_slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.foto_slider',
  focusOnSelect: true,
  centerMode: true,
  infinite: false,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD2**
Самое главное забыл: перезапускать после клика на пункт меню нужно ОБА слайдера - и сам слайдер и слайдер-навигацию. Иначе могут быть сбои в работе. Проверьте этот момент.

**UPD**
Я попробовал сделать Ваш пример воспроизводимым, и у меня есть подозрение, что проблема не в infinite, а в variableWidth: true и adaptiveHeight: true. С этими параметрами мой пример работает криво, без них всё ок:

```js
$('.foto_slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.foto_slider-nav'
});

$('.foto_slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.foto_slider',
  focusOnSelect: true,
  centerMode: true
});
```

```css
.foto_slider {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.foto_slider-nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.foto_slider img,
.foto_slider-nav img {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="foto_slider">
  <div><img src="" alt="123"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="456"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="789"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="abc"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="def"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="igk"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="lmn"></div>
</div>
<div class="foto_slider-nav">
  <div><img src="" alt="123"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="456"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="789"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="abc"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="def"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="igk"></div>
  <div><img src="" alt="lmn"></div>
</div>
```

---

Вам нужно перезапустить Ваш слайдер после выбора соответствующего пункта меню:

```
$('.foto').click(function(){ //кликаем по пункту в меню
    $('.slider').slick('reinit'); //перезапускаем слайдер
}
```

Comment: Лучше $(".slider").slick('setPosition');

Comment: Спасибо огромное, наконец то работает как надо. Не додумался его перезапускать (( Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Только появился один неприятный момент. Слайдер встал на место но теперь превью работают немного не корректно, превью не совпадает с главным слайдером. Если поставить infinite: false то все работает хорошо, но клиент хочет постоянную прокрутку (

Comment: @Cowboy, без воспроизводимого примера трудно что-то подсказать - если приведёте работающий код, попробую помочь

Comment: У меня слайдер без этих свойств вообще сходит с ума, начинает кидать на разные слайды при нажатие на превью, но я вижу в вашем примере что листается правильно, пойду смотреть, что с ним происходит, спасибо еще раз за помощь!

Comment: @Cowboy, я добавил второй upd - посмотрите, может быть именно в этом проблема.

Comment: Да, момент с перезагрузкой я проверил, там оба перезагружаются.

Comment: К сожалению ни чего не помогло, пришлось оставить без цикла слайдер пока что, спасибо еще раз за помощь!